# Problem with nested attributes for Devise registration page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to add `Address` nested attributes for `User`. 
But only `user_id` hits the `addresses` table when I submit, and not `country` `city` `street` and `zip_code`

### user.rb

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :name, :age, :email

  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

### address.rb

```
  attr_accessor :country, :city, :zip_code, :street

  belongs_to :user
```

### appication_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
...
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :age, 
  address_attributes: [:country, :city, :zip_code, :street]])
end
```

### The form

```
  <% resource.build_address %>

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :age %><br />
      <%= f.number_field :age, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <h4>Address</h4>

    <%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= address.label :country %>
        <%= address.text_field :country, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= address.label :city %>
        <%= address.text_field :city, class: 'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= address.label :street %>
        <%= address.text_field :street, class: 'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= address.label :zip_code %>
        <%= address.text_field :zip_code, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

    <% end %>


    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Remove `attr_accessor :country, :city, :zip_code, :street`. Don't use `attr_accessor` for database backed attributes in ActiveRecord. It will overwrite the setters that actually make it work.

Comment: You're right, it fixed the issue, thanks